# reputation points gained in answers

Tags: discussion, reputation

Is there a way in calculating the total number of reputation points one gained only on his/her answers?
Currently the reputation points for questions and answers are combined total.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such current mechanism. You could request it as some type of stat feature, or you could go through the data dumps and calculate in that manner.

Answer (score 4):

To answer the question as the others have, you can use Data Explorer; specifically, [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/144081/total-reputation-from-posts-by-post-type), which does it by all post types:

```sql
select pt.Name
     , sum(case when v.VoteTypeId = 2 then 10
                when v.VoteTypeId = 3 then -2
           end) as [Post Reputation]
     , sum(case when v.VoteTypeId = 2 then 10
                when v.VoteTypeId = 3 then -2
                when v.VoteTypeId = 1 and pt.Id = 1 then 2
                when v.VoteTypeId = 1 and pt.Id = 2 then 15
           end) as [Post Reputation, inc. accepts]
     , sum(case when v.VoteTypeId = 16 then 2 end) as [Approved Edits]
  from Posts p
  join Votes v
    on p.Id = v.PostId
  join PostTypes pt
    on p.PostTypeId = pt.Id
 where p.OwnerUserId = ##UserID##
 group by pt.Name
```

It won't give you any information on upvotes since the last update of the Data Explorer database, which is typically weekly.

Comment: You beat me to it. Add on score by questions, and score by other, and it'd be even more awesome.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, use the raw data dump and count the upvotes on answers only.

Comment: Any automated stats?

Comment: not necessarily, upvotes after the cap limit will not be counted.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no such mechanism on this platform.

Maybe something for the future?

Answer (score 0):

Since in general it is not possible to exactly calculate rep from any particular posts (see [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20592/calculating-rep-earned-using-sandbox-or-data-dump)), the answer is **no**.  If you don't care about things like the reputation cap and community wiki, then you can get a rough estimate.